# Combinatorial identity of Derivatives of super-Gaussian function

Tags: co.combinatorics, integration, differential-calculus

An asymptotic expansion I stumbled upon has real numbers $c^\alpha_{ij}$ as coefficients, where $i, j \in \mathbb{N}_0$ are non-negative integers and $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}_0^n$ is a multi-index. They are defined as follows. First define $\theta \in (0, 1]$ the radially symmetric function
$$E_\theta(\xi) := e^{-\theta|\xi|^{2m}}$$
on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Now $c_{ij}^\alpha$ is defined by
$$c_{ij}^\alpha := \int_0^1 \theta^i (1-\theta)^j D^\alpha\{E_\theta * E_{(1-\theta)}\}(0) \,\mathrm{d} \theta,$$
where $D^\alpha = D_1^{\alpha_1} \cdots D_n^{\alpha_n}$ denotes differentiation by the multi-index $\alpha$ and $*$ denotes convolution.

**Question:** What is an explicit formula for the $c_{ij}^\alpha$?

The expression $D^\alpha\{E_\theta * E_{(1-\theta)}\}(0)$ alone is easily seen to be of the form
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-|\xi|^{2m}} P_\alpha(\xi, \theta) \mathrm{d} \xi,$$
where $P_\alpha(\xi, \theta)$ is some polynomial in $\theta$ and $\xi$, depending on $\alpha$. Because the integral ends up being essentially a Gamma integral times an integral of a polynomial over a sphere, one sees that only those terms in $P_\alpha(\xi, \theta)$ are relevant that are of the form $|\xi|^{2k}\theta^l$ for some $k, l$. But how do I know which multi-indices $\alpha$ produce such polynomials? Does anybody have an idea? Also: does maybe the integral over $\theta$ help?